# share Volume from container to host docker-compose

Tags: docker, devops, volumes

I need to mount my data inside the container to my local. I am trying to mount the data inside my conatiner path - /usr/local/nagios/etc/objects/command.cfg, i couldnt find a proper way to mount. when i trying to do the mounted floder is empty not files or conentet available.

MY dockerfile

version: '3'

services:
nagios-core:
build:
context: .
target: build-nagios
container_name: nagios-container-poc
image: nagios-core:4.4.9
ports:
- "8080:80"
environment:
- nagiosadmin_user=
- nagiosadmin_password=
command: /start.sh
volumes:
- /nagios/etc/object/commands.cfg:/usr/local/nagios/etc/object/commands.cfg

Comment: What does the `/nagios/etc/object/commands.cfg` path contain on your host? Is it empty?

Comment: The linked question describes a path to create a named volume backed by a host directory.  This will use Docker's (mis)feature of copying image contents into empty named volumes, so you'll get a (initial) copy of the image config files on your host, that you can then edit.

Comment: @Ludal there are some default configurations are ther. Ineed to add some more configurations in the file. Thanks